# Importing python module when running apache server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run a flask application on Apache hosted on AWS.

The following is my flaskapp.wsgi

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')

from flaskapp import app as application
```

The following is my setup.py where my Flask application resides.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def login():
        return render_template("login.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The log file at */var/log/apache2/error.log* shows that

*ImportError: No module named requests*

The webpage shows *Internal Server Error* when I navigate to public IP address of the server.

I did *pip install requests* in the server, restarted the server, yet the problem persists. Running the Flask server locally, I don't get this error. How do I fix this? I'm using all of those modules imported. I'm not working with virtualenv.

Comment: Did you setup the environment on AWS with virtualenv? I've personally made the mistake in past of setting up with virtualenv and then not installing all required packages in that virtual environment.

Comment: no, i'm not working with virtualenv

Comment: What version of Python is mod_wsgi compiled for? http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use Maybe it is using different Python version if there are multiple on the system.